# how to count hindi string in array with php and count how many letter and vowel in string

Tags: php, hindi

I have something like

```
$a = "आलोक"
```

I want to achieve something like in php

```
a[0] = आ  
a[1] = लो  
a[3] = क
```

I want counting in numbers like :-
 i put a name आलोक 
 i want output like letter=3 and vowel=2 
because in आलोक 
first letter (आ), 
second letter (लो) 
and third letter is (क).
 so out put become is letter= 3 
and for vowel , 
first vowel ( ा) and 
second vowel( ो) 
so out put vowel=2

name can be dynamic not static

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to break hindi string in array with php and count how many letter and vowel in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689852/how-to-break-hindi-string-in-array-with-php-and-count-how-many-letter-and-vowel)

Comment: not a duplicate their is only break string but not counting of letters and vowel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through the other question you had posted and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26689956/1083314) suggests a function on the following lines to break up the string into characters:

```
 function mbStringToArray ($string) {
  $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
   while ($strlen) {
    $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
    $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
  }
  return $array;
 } 
  $a = "आलोक"; 
  print_r(mbStringToArray($a));
```

If you run this code, it will give you the following output:

```
  Array
  (
   [0] => आ
   [1] => ल
   [2] => ो
   [3] => क
  )
```

I'm going to build upon this function and just extend it a little bit and you'll be able to get the count of vowels and consonants easily.

Thankfully, I found this [handy guide](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf) on the UTF-8 encodings of all the characters in the Devnagri script. Another simple tool to confirm and sort of get the decimal and octal representations as well for this characters is http://unicodelookup.com/.

From the table, I [looked up](http://unicodelookup.com/#0x093F/1) `0x093F` and easily cross referenced it with  ि.

Now once you have this, it's just a matter of getting the decoded unicode character from the HEX code. You can achieve that easily with :

```
echo json_decode('"\u093F"'); //Ouputs  ि
```

I have combined these steps together in a function called `countVowels`:

```
 function countVowels ($req){

   //I have hard coded the hex values of some characters that are vowels in Hindi
   //This does NOT include all the vowels
   //You might want to add more as per your needs from the table that I have provided before

   $hindi = array("\u0906","\u0908","\u093E","\u093F","\u0945","\u0946","\u0947","\u0948","\u0949","\u094A","\u094B","\u094C","\u094D");
   $vowels= array();
   $vowelcount = 0;
   for($i = 0; $i<count($hindi); $i++){

     //Push the decoded unicode character into the $vowels array
     array_push($vowels,json_decode('"'.$hindi[$i].'"')); 
   }

   for($j=0;$j<count($req);$j++){
      if(in_array($req[$j], $vowels))
        $vowelcount++;
   }
   return $vowelcount;
 }
```

The input to this function is `$req` which could be the output array for the previously defined function `mbStringToArray`. Once you have the count of vowels, you can easily get the count of other consonants. The flow might look something like:

```
  $a = "आलोक"; 
  $arr = mbStringToArray($a)
  $vows = countVowels($arr); //Number of vowels 
  $cons = count($arr) - $vows; //Number of consonants
```

So in this case, the consonants returned would be 2 and vowels would also be 2. That's because I have hardcoded आ as a vowel and therefore it gets accounted for in the `countVowels` function. Have a look at the [working demo](http://3v4l.org/HTSWO).

You can modify the array I use there and take care of such discrepancies as per your requirements. I hope this gets you started in the right direction.