# How to count real total number of chars in a string?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the question is silly. I need to count real number of chars in a string. For example I have the following string:

`हा य`

With `.length` I have the following result:

```js
let chars = "हा य";
console.log(chars.length);

for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
 console.log(chars[i]);
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it's wrong. I have three chars here:

This one - `हा`,  - this one (empty space) and `य` this one. Which is proper and shortest way to count it correctly?

Comment: this character is hidden, "ह"

Comment: `"हा"` consists of two characters: `"ह"` and `"ा"`.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez No. The first character is being treated as two by breaking it into separate parts.

Comment: https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-count-unicode-characters-in-javascript/

Comment: Its two chars right?

Comment: @AshikPaul There's a space between them.

Comment: @palaѕн Why do you mean? `हा` - one, `<empty space>`, - two, `य` - three. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689852/how-to-break-hindi-string-in-array-with-php-and-count-how-many-letter-and-vowel

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak, no `हा` is two. The other two are one each.

Comment: So, you mean `ह` & `हा` means same thing?

Comment: I don't know about Hindi alphabet, but I am guessing that in order to avoid a large number of different characters for many combinations, the `ा'` is a separate modifier character. Comper with the Unicode for phonetic alphabet symbols - see https://ipa.typeit.org/full/ and try typing a letter then using one of the modifiers on the bottom row of symbols, and then press backspace to remove them one at a time.

Comment: I just don't know hindi. Is there some language rule, when `हा` is two chars?

Comment: I don't think the modifier counts as a separate character, any more than e.g. `é` counts as two characters even though it consists of character `e` and a modifier `´`.

Comment: @GuyIncognito The number of possible accented letters in European languages (combinations of letter plus accent) is not that many, so it is feasible to have separate characters for them all. I am guessing that there is a bigger matrix of possible combinations in this case, although speculation because I don't know any Hindi.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak So I guess that from a practical point of view, if what you mean by "real length" is such that `हा` ought to count as one, then you would have to find out what modifier characters exist, and exclude them from the count.

Comment: Thank you for discussion!!! Could someone please tell me, is this this symbol`ा`exists only for Hindi or not?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak You would need an expert in Asian languages. The Devanagari script is used for many languages in addition to just Hindi.

Comment: Actually, I can count letters in the string without counting this symbol `ा. But I'm not sure will it work for other languages.

Comment: Well I am guessing that if it could ever be meaningfully used standalone, then fonts would not have been designed in such a way that if you do so then you get a circle displayed next to it (clearly in order to represent where the character being modified would be). So I would guess that it is only ever used in combination with whatever it is attached to. But there is more information at https://hindilanguage.info/lessons/lesson-2-devanagari-vowels/ - see the bit about maatraa forms.

Comment: So it seems likely that without a preceding consonant `आ` would be used instead, in any language which uses that script. This based on the web page that I just linked.

Comment: You could also argue that as `हा` actually represents two sounds (consonant followed by vowel) it is reasonable to count it as two in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

For all languages you can try [Count number of characters present in foreign language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815678/count-number-of-characters-present-in-foreign-language)

```js
function countChars(text){
  return text.split("").filter( function(char){ 
let charCode = char.charCodeAt(); return charCode >= 2309 && charCode <=2361 || charCode == 32;
  }).length;
}

let chars = "हा य";
console.log(countChars(chars));
```

Comment: If we go by what the OP is expecting, then your function should return 3, not 2.

Comment: Could you explain what this code does and why? Specifically what's the purpose of `charCode >= 2309 && charCode <=2361`?

Comment: @GuyIncognito https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/southasia/devanagari/devanagarichart/

Comment: @guy incognito. What I know this is the character code range for Hindi language

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have updated the answer. Now it accepts space

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question is not "count the number of Hindi characters". I'm pretty sure they want to count any characters, not Hindi specifically.

Comment: @GuyIncognito if that's true he wouldn't be asking us. He will just go with ```.length```

Comment: Uh, no. "Any characters" includes Hindi so .length gives a wrong answer like shown in the question.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Hmmm. I guess we will have to wait for OP's comments

Comment: I actually need to count the actual number of characters in a string in different languages. Not just Hindi. But also Thai and Indonesian. If this symbol ` ा` is present in all such languages, then we can count the length without it. Can this be the solution?

Comment: Sorry, this won't help you with all languages.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak I have updated the answer for other languages. This may help others too.